# how to pass language between templates in django admin

Tags: django, internationalization, django-admin

I 'm overriding django-admin templates to add a language choice links.

I added this:

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
{% for language in languages %}
        <a href="/{{ language.code }}{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'3:' }}"
           class="{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}selected{% endif %}"
           lang="{{ language.code }}">
            {{ language.name_local }}
        </a>

{% endfor %}
```

in both `base_site.html` and `login.html`.
They work fine

The problem is that I always get the default language in the dashboard.

For example:

If I choose Frensh in the login  page, the login page gets translated into frensh but after I login, I find the dashboard and other pages in the default language.

How can I fix this, in order to display the dashboard in the language chosen from the login page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it.

I changed the `href` in the `login.html` as follows:

```
            <a href="/{{ language.code }}{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'3:23' }}{{ language.code }}/admin/"
```

Infact, the `login` url is as follows : `/fr/admin/login/?next=/fr/admin/`

so I need to keep in mind the next page url.

I just needed to change the language code in the actual page `slice:'3:'` and in the next page `slice:':23'`.